# writing to a file python, NoneType' object is not iterable error

Tags: python, file, typeerror

I have written a function which reads in data from external files and produces lists. the program works fine and I have a list of numbers for each file read in. But i am new to python and am struggling to save it to a file this is my program and savefile lines:

```
def meanarr(image, res=None):
 "costruct code which runs over a single ccd to get the means"
 a=pyfits.getdata(image).MAG_AUTO
 q=numpy.mean(a)
 s=pyfits.getdata(image).X2WIN_IMAGE
 j=numpy.mean(s)
 f=pyfits.getdata(image).Y2WIN_IMAGE
 z=numpy.mean(f)
 g=pyfits.getdata(image).XYWIN_IMAGE
 h= abs(numpy.mean(g))
 a=[q,j,z,h]
 print a
 return res


for arg in sys.argv[1:5]:
        #print arg
        s = meanarr(arg) #meanarr is my function

datafile = open('writetest.txt', 'w')
for l in meanarr(arg):
     datafile.write(l)
datafile.close()
```

but i am getting an error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` and I'm not sure why because my function does produce data. can anybody help?

Comment: Where is the `meanarr` function? You forgot to paste it.

Comment: o yeah, I've put it in now

Comment: `meanarr()` is doing something to `arg` that is not doing what you think its doing. please post `meanarr()` because whatever its returning, is probably not a list.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `meanarr()` to return?  It seems like you want it to return some stringlike representation of the data (e.g. `str(a)`.)  But you never tell it to do this.

Comment: yeah i think i want it to return str(a), it half works now thank you.

Comment: Actually, I think you wants to return some iterable full of multiple strings, like `map(str, a)`. If you just return a string, the loop is going to go character by character, which is a silly thing to do.

Comment: but when it saves everything is in one big line but i want each a to be on its own line how do i do this?

Comment: @user2201043: That's what you get for returning one big string with no newlines, and writing each character of that string. If you want to print the string representations of `q`, `j`, `z`, and `h`, each on a separate line, you can, e.g., `return [str(x) + '\n' for x in a]`.

Comment: @user2201043: But you really need to understand the difference between strings and lists, and how to write lines, and so on; just trying to use code that doesn't mean anything to you is not going to get you very far.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Yeah I am starting realize I need to properly understand this stuff before I go any further. That return didn't work it just produced /n at the end of every data point but i'll try to figure out whats gone on. But thanks for the other help

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because of the `meanarr` function: `res` is always `None`. 
The `for` loop needs an iterable.

**Btw:**

It seems like the `for` loop in the following code:

```
for arg in sys.argv[1:5]:
    #print arg
    s = meanarr(arg) #meanarr is my function
```

is problematic since the `s` variable is overidden at each iteration.

You probably meant:

```
s = [meanarr(arg) for arg in sys.argv[1:5]]
```

However I'm not clear about where you want to use `s` since you don't seem to use it in your code.

Comment: okay, so im not sure why i even had res in my code I dont think it was needed. so ive deleted it, I thought my iterable was my input file sys.argv[1:5] but im not sure.

Comment: ah, okay that might be an issue. I'm new to this. on my command line i see all the answer coming out but obviously each previous one will be overwritten. how would you suggest I change it so i have a set of results that arent overwriting the previous ones?

Comment: Well, `meanarr` does have side-effects, like printing something out, so the `for` loop may not be useless. (But when calling a function purely for side-effects, it's a _lot_ clearer to just ignore any result, instead of assigning it to a variable you never look at.)

Comment: i found my problem,  i needed to return str(a)

Answer (score 1):

In your `meanarr` function, you return `None` which cannot be iterated over!

```
def meanarr(image, res=None):
 "costruct code which runs over a single ccd to get the means"
 a=pyfits.getdata(image).MAG_AUTO
 q=numpy.mean(a)
 s=pyfits.getdata(image).X2WIN_IMAGE
 j=numpy.mean(s)
 f=pyfits.getdata(image).Y2WIN_IMAGE
 z=numpy.mean(f)
 g=pyfits.getdata(image).XYWIN_IMAGE
 h= abs(numpy.mean(g))
 a=[q,j,z,h]
 print a
 return res
```

When you call this function, you do not specify `res` which gets the value of None and is returned as such, hence the error.

See the following example and try to relate it to your code.

```
>>> def testFunc(test, res = None):
         test = 10
         return res

>>> type(testFunc(10))
<type 'NoneType'>
>>> type(testFunc(10, [1, 2, 3]))
<type 'list'>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def meanarr(image, res=None):
```

at this point res=None

then nowhere in your code, do you do anything to res

next time anything happens with res

```
return res
```

so it returns `None`

so your code can almost be simplified as

```
def meanarr():
   return None
```